# Merge aggregate group rows in Kendo UI Grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am showing aggregate data in Kendo UI Grid. I show a grid with grouped data. However i need to add a new column which is an aggregate of another column rows of a particular group (as shown below).

[image]

**Column4 shows aggregate of column3 values.**

I tried Kendo UI documentation however this seems to be pretty specific and could not find anything. Do I need custom implementation for this or does Kendo UI grid have this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate values can be accessed declaratively in the [`footerTemplate`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.footerTemplate) and [`groupFooterTemplate`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.groupFooterTemplate), or programmatically from the data items. The following answer demonstrates all these options:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40139348/3086237

However, the Grid does not provide means to place aggregate values in regular data rows declaratively. Generally, this doesn't make sense, as the same value will appear in all rows from a specific group. If you really need an aggregate value inside a data row, you will have to obtain it programmatically in [`dataBound`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-dataBound) and then inject it in the desired table cell via DOM manipulation.